# Duplicate column name in Document Library Setting

Tags: document-library, content-type, sharepoint-on-prem

I have figured out that our document library columns have duplicate columns.
We are using the content type. When I'm going to compare this duplicate column name, it is showing like below with extra "0".

&Field=Department0

&Field=Department

It's strange why this duplicate column happen. All the information entered to this column can see on the list but cannot get on the item edit/view.

When we implemented this library was only one column for each field. How should I return back to the original state without losing information on each documents.

Looking forward to see solution, if anyone has similar issue. Thanks All.

Comment: Did you by any chance use "Content and Structure" to copy some documents?

Comment: so you have situation that both fields contain some value or just one. If just one you can use Sharepoitn Manger (or powerShell) to delete the column. If both you would have to first write some powershell so you move values from one column to another and then delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, Harshal. I figured it out that I did the document moving through the Content and Structure. I didn't realized that the document source (actually Archive library) does not use the Content Type as in Destination library. It was messed up the library structure in Destination. Hope you had same issue before :D. Thanks for your comments. It's really helpful.

Hi Marek, If I delete the column, the original column is gone. Need to recreate the column to map with content type but it mess up on the metadata info, some get, some lose. Thanks for your comments.

Finally, restored the database on the last fine backup. :)